# What clips my wings?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have the Collector's Edition of Diablo 3 and I love the little set of angel wings you get. I notice that when I log into the game again I have to re-use my item to apply the wings to my character.

What I can not figure out is why they some times just up and vanish however. I have tried testing out teleporting and using the town portal to hop in and out but it has not caused my wings to disappear as of yet.

Does anyone know what could be causing this besides starting a new game?

Oh, and is there a way to just make the wings permanent in some manner?

Comment: I'm jealous, I want wings! But anyways, is it related to the server resets they've been doing lately? Or is it anytime you logout/login?

Comment: It so far appears to be when I log in/out (though I will admit they do coincide pretty well with the server restarts as of late).

Comment: i got my CE how do i activate the wings?

Comment: @hakkushaku Have them in your inventory and right click them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that logging out of the game or dying will definitely cause your wings to disappear, at least from what I've observed. I'm sure server resets and rollbacks could cause similar issues as well.

From what I've discovered so far, there is no way to make them permanent.

The wings are pretty awesome! I just wish they could be hot-keyed, instead of having to open the inventory and click to toggle them. Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

Death will also cause your wings to fall off.